# Appended Content is Not Triggering - Even using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup

I append the following content using jQuery to create a lightbox style popup that loads loads content using AJAX:

```html
<div id="framebox-overlay">
  <div id="framebox-wrapper">
    <div id="framebox-nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#prev" class="framebox-prev framebox-nav">Previous</a>
      <a href="#next" class="framebox-next framebox-nav">Next</a>
    </div>
    <section id="framebox-content">
      <!--AJAX to insert #single-project-wrapper content here-->
    </section>
    <div id="framebox-close">
      <p>Click to close</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the appended next/previous links to work (`.framebox-next` and `.framebox-prev` as shown above), however the links are not triggering properly:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('.framebox-trigger').click(function(e){
    // Code that appends lightbox HTML and loads initial AJAX content goes here
  });

  // Code that isn't working:

  $('body').on('click', 'a .framebox-next', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //remove and add selected class
    var next = $('#portfolio-wrapper li.current-link').next('li > a');
    $('#portfolio-wrapper li.current-link').removeClass('current-link');
    $(next).addClass('current-link');

    //fade out and fade in
    var nexthref = $('#portfolio-wrapper li.current-link a').attr('href');
    $('#single-page-wrapper').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      var current = $('#portfolio-wrapper li.current-link a');
      $(this).load(nexthref + " #single-page-wrapper", function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('fast');
      });
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

This last bit of code is not doing anything to the appended link `.framebox-next`. I have looked for other answers, and it seems that the `.on()` method should be effecting appended content.

Any help or input would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is wrong for `.framebox-next`. You have a space between `a` and `.framebox-next` which would mean `.framebox-next` needs to be a child of the `a` element.

Use this selector instead:

```
 $('body').on('click', 'a.framebox-next', function(e) {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: @Jonast92 had to wait for time to allow it - it was answered so quickly!